# pygame event input box

Tags: python, events, pygame, inputbox

I'm working on a game but i don't quite understand how the event handling works. I want to make it so when the player inputs the correct first number of 6-digit number the, keyboard focus will be on the input box to the right, but i have a very limited understanding of Pygame and i have been scratching my head and searching for a solution for a while. i'd be very grateful if someone could help.

```
# Import needed sub-programs to act as tools with given function
import pygame
import time
import random

# Initialising pygame sub-program
pygame.init()

# Calling height and width of the frame of the program as Variables
display_height = 900
display_width = 600

# Changing essential colours from RGB colour code to Variables
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
grey = (96, 96, 96)
yellow = (255, 233, 0)
orange = (255, 147, 7)
orange2 = (255, 102, 0)
dark_orange = (175, 105, 0)
green = (0, 255, 12)
dark_green = (3, 130, 8)
dark_red = (114, 9, 0)
brown = (81, 48, 16)
red = (255,0,0)
blue = (0,97,255)

# Sets the height and width of program using variables on lines 7, 8
gamedisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_height,display_width))

# Sets title of the Window
pygame.display.set_caption('For-Get-Ful')

# A variable to set up a method of maintaining a certain FPS count
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Starts the program background off as white from Variable line 12
gamedisplay.fill(white)

# Update the screen to show off the colour implemented on line 38
pygame.display.flip()

# A tool to display any text on any surface
def text_objects(text, font, color):
textSurface = font.render(text, True, color)
return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

# a tool to display the in-game numbers
def game_subject(text,dw,dh):
largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText, black)
TextRect.center = (dw,dh)
gamedisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

def game_loop():
font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 200)
text1 = ''
text2 = ''
text3 = ''
text4 = ''
text5 = ''
text6 = ''

# In-game random 6-digit number generator
subject1 = random.randint(1,9)
subject1 = str(subject1)

subject2 = random.randint(1,9)
subject2 = str(subject2)

subject3 = random.randint(1,9)
subject3 = str(subject3)

subject4 = random.randint(1,9)
subject4 = str(subject4)

subject5 = random.randint(1,9)
subject5 = str(subject5)

subject6 = random.randint(1,9)
subject6 = str(subject6)

subjects_tog = (subject1,subject2,subject3,subject4,subject5,subject6)
subjects_tog = str(subjects_tog)

# In-game objects
time_bar = pygame.Rect(0,590,900,80)

# In-game objects
time_bar_2 = pygame.Rect(0,270,900,35)

# In-game objects
time_bar_3 = pygame.Rect(0,315,900,25)

# In-game objects
time_bar_4 = pygame.Rect(0,350,900,15)

input_box = pygame.Rect(5,375,140,205)
input_box_2 = pygame.Rect(155,375,140,205)
input_box_3 = pygame.Rect(305,375,140,205)
input_box_4 = pygame.Rect(455,375,140,205)
input_box_5 = pygame.Rect(605,375,140,205)
input_box_6 = pygame.Rect(755,375,140,205)

# Random box color generator
subject_color = (blue,green,red,yellow)
ran_color1 = random.choice(subject_color)
ran_color2 = random.choice(subject_color)
ran_color3 = random.choice(subject_color)
ran_color4 = random.choice(subject_color)
ran_color5 = random.choice(subject_color)
ran_color6 = random.choice(subject_color)
ran_color7 = random.choice(subject_color)
ran_color8 = random.choice(subject_color)
ran_color9 = random.choice(subject_color)
ran_color10 = random.choice(subject_color)
```

here is where my problem is!!

```
loop = True

# To keep the game running longer than 1 frame
while loop:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
          pygame.quit()
          quit()
      pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
      if pressed[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
         game_intro()
      elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
              if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                  if text1 == subject1:
                      text1 = str(text1)
                      print("correct")
                  text1 = ''
              elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                  text1 = text1[:-1]
              else:
                  text1 += event.unicode

  pygame.display.update()
  gamedisplay.fill(black)
  txt_surface = font.render(text1, True, black)
  txt_surface2 = font.render(text2, True, black)
  txt_surface3 = font.render(text3, True, black)
  txt_surface4 = font.render(text4, True, black)
  txt_surface5 = font.render(text5, True, black)
  txt_surface6 = font.render(text6, True, black)

  pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, ran_color5, input_box)
  gamedisplay.blit(txt_surface, (input_box.x+5, input_box.y+5))

  pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, ran_color6, input_box_2)
  gamedisplay.blit(txt_surface2, (input_box_2.x+5, input_box_2.y+5))

  pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, ran_color7, input_box_3)
  gamedisplay.blit(txt_surface3, (input_box_3.x+5, input_box_3.y+5))

  pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, ran_color8, input_box_4)
  gamedisplay.blit(txt_surface4, (input_box_4.x+5, input_box_4.y+5))

  pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, ran_color9, input_box_5)
  gamedisplay.blit(txt_surface5, (input_box_5.x+5, input_box_5.y+5))

  pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, ran_color10, input_box_6)
  gamedisplay.blit(txt_surface6, (input_box_6.x+5, input_box_6.y+5))

  # Subject display squares
  pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, orange,(5,10,140,250))
  pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, orange,(155,10,140,250))
  pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, orange,(305,10,140,250))
  pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, orange,(455,10,140,250))
  pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, orange,(605,10,140,250))
  pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, orange,(755,10,140,250))

  # Time bar and its function
  pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, ran_color1, time_bar)
  time_bar_numb = time_bar.move_ip(-2,0)

  # Time bar and its function
  pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, ran_color2, time_bar_2)
  time_bar_numb_2 = time_bar_2.move_ip(+2,0)

  # Time bar and its function
  pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, ran_color3, time_bar_3)
  time_bar_numb_3 = time_bar_3.move_ip(-2,0)

  # Time bar and its function
  pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, ran_color4, time_bar_4)
  time_bar_numb_4 = time_bar_4.move_ip(+2,0)

  # Random in-game subject numbers
  game_subject(subject1,73.5,140)
  game_subject(subject2,225,140)
  game_subject(subject3,375,140)
  game_subject(subject4,525,140)
  game_subject(subject5,675,140)
  game_subject(subject6,827,140)

  pygame.display.update()
  clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Not an answer; just a tip: All these variable names that ends in numbers (`ran_colorX`, `txt_surfaceX`, `input_box_X`) should probably be replaced by a list instead. That makes it dynamic, easier to read, less code, and you can iterate through it using a for loop. Currently, to remove or add code will require you to change many places in your source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd put the `input_box` rects into a list and then use `for` loops to draw the boxes and blit the numbers. You can use only one `text` variable instead of `text1`, `text2`, etc. and iterate over the characters in this variable to blit them.

The built-in [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function can be used to zip the text and the boxes together, so that you have the number and the coordinates available at the same time (alternatively use indexes).

```
input_boxes = [
    pygame.Rect(5,375,140,205),
    pygame.Rect(155,375,140,205),
    pygame.Rect(305,375,140,205),
    pygame.Rect(455,375,140,205),
    pygame.Rect(605,375,140,205),
    pygame.Rect(755,375,140,205),
    ]
```

In the while loop:

```
# Draw the boxes.
for box in input_boxes:
    pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, ran_color1, box)

# Blit one number after the other at the corresponding box.
for number, box in zip(text, input_boxes):
    txt_surface = font.render(number, True, black)
    gamedisplay.blit(txt_surface, (box.x+5, box.y+5))
```

If you're not familiar with the `zip` function, you can use indexes:

```
for i in range(len(text)):
    txt_surface = font.render(text[i], True, black)
    gamedisplay.blit(txt_surface, (input_boxes[i].x+5, input_boxes[i].y+5))
```